# Iterating and making combinations of elements stored in three arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, combinations, permutation

```
HashMap<String, Set<ArrayList<String>>> alMealtypeComb = new HashMap<>();
                    for (int nextCount = 0; nextCount < roomListHM.get("Room"+checkIndex).size(); nextCount++) {
                        if(checkIndex<roomIndexCounter-1)
                        {
                            checkIndex++;
                        }
                        for (int outter = 1; outter < roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount).get(maxIndex).size(); outter++) {
                            alcombination = new ArrayList<>();

                            permutations = new ArrayList<>();
                            if (roomIndexCounter > 1) {
                                roomDataCounter = 1;
                            }

                            int data;

                            start: for (int roomComb = 0; roomComb < valueSize; roomComb++) {
                                if (roomIndexCounter > roomComb) {
                                    chflag = false;
                                    if (!chflag && roomIndexCounter != 1) {
                                        if ((roomListHM.get("Room" + roomComb).get(roomComb)).contains(roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount)
                                                .get(maxIndex).get(outter))) {
                                            keyMealType = roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount).get(maxIndex).get(outter);
                                            alcombination.add(roomListHM.get("Room" + roomComb).get(nextCount).get(0) + "--" + roomComb + "--"
                                                    + keyMealType);
                                            chflag = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    chflag = false;
                                    if (!chflag && roomIndexCounter != 1) {
                                        if ((roomListHM.get("Room" + roomComb).get(roomComb)).contains(roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount)
                                                .get(maxIndex).get(outter))) {
                                            keyMealType = roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount).get(maxIndex).get(outter);
                                            alcombination.add(roomListHM.get("Room" + roomComb).get(roomComb).get(0) + "--" + roomComb + "--"
                                                    + keyMealType);
                                            chflag = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                //}

                                    if ((roomListHM.get("Room" + roomDataCounter).get(roomComb)).contains(roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount)
                                            .get(maxIndex).get(outter))) {
                                        keyMealType = roomListHM.get("Room" + roomCount).get(maxIndex).get(outter);
                                        alcombination.add(roomListHM.get("Room" + roomDataCounter).get(roomComb).get(0) + "--" + roomDataCounter
                                                + "--" + keyMealType);

                                    }

                                    if (roomDataCounter < roomIndexCounter && roomComb == valueSize - 1 && roomIndexCounter != 1) {

                                        roomDataCounter++;
                                        continue start;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            roomCombination(new ArrayList<String>(), alcombination);
                            for (int j = 0; j < permutations.size(); j++) {
                                if (permutations.get(j).size() != roomIndexCounter) {
                                    permutations.remove(j);

                                    j--;

                                }
                            }
                            if (roomIndexCounter > 1) {

                                for (int j = 0; j < permutations.size(); j++) {
                                    int check = 0;

                                    if (roomIndexCounter == 2) {
                                        if ((permutations.get(j).toString()).contains("" + 0 + "")
                                                && (permutations.get(j).toString()).contains("" + 1 + "")) {
                                            continue;

                                        } else {
                                            permutations.remove(j);
                                            j--;

                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (roomIndexCounter == 3) {
                                        if ((permutations.get(j).toString()).contains("" + 0 + "")
                                                && (permutations.get(j).toString()).contains("" + 1 + "")
                                                && (permutations.get(j).toString()).contains("" + 2 + "")) {
                                            continue;

                                        } else {
                                            permutations.remove(j);
                                            j--;

                                        }
                                    }


                                }
                            }

                             Set<ArrayList<String>> newSet=new
                             HashSet<>(permutations);
                             System.out.println("set value*********"+newSet);

                            //alMealtypeComb.put(keyMealType, permutations);
                            alMealtypeComb.put(keyMealType, newSet);

                            System.out.println("result" + permutations);

                        }
                    }
                    hmRoomCombionation.put("Room" + roomCount, alMealtypeComb);

                }

                System.out.println("**********************" + hmRoomCombionation);

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return alHotelResult;
}

// combination with recursion

public static void roomCombination(ArrayList<String> sub, ArrayList<String> letterArray) {
    permutations.add(sub);
    if (letterArray.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> prefix = new ArrayList<String>(sub);
            prefix.add(letterArray.get(i));
            ArrayList<String> postfix = new ArrayList<String>(letterArray);
            postfix.remove(i);
            roomCombination(prefix, postfix);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to iterate and form combinations of elements stored in an ArrayList with size specified.

For example:

Suppose we have three arraylist as follows:

```
Room1[DLX1-HB,DLX1-FB,DLX1-RO,CLB1-HB,CLB1-FB,CLB1-RO]

Room2[DLX2-HB,DLX2-FB,DLX2-RO,DLX2-BF,CLB2-HB,CLB2-FB,CLB2-RO] 

Room3[DLX3-HB,DLX3-FB,DLX3-RO,CLB3-HB,CLB3-FB,CLB3-RO,CLB3-BF]
```

In this scenario i need combinations of 3.

Example output:

```
[DLX1-HB,DLX2-HB,DLX3-HB]

[DLX1-HB,CLB2-HB,DLX3-HB]

[DLX1-FB,DLX2-FB,DLX3-FB]

.

.
```

And the pattern follows.

Please provide me the optimized solution with minimum looping.

Comment: Any effort from your side?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not ask questions that ask us to perform your work. You should put some effort in the problem and ask if you face any particular issue. StackOverflow is not a good fit for such questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to solve a problem without any effort.

Comment: Please provide us with a minimum sign of effort.

Comment: I tried putting the value in a HashMap keeping Room number(room1) as key and and arraylist of arraylist as values.but the looping was too much and it hampers my performance when the result is too large

Comment: Try to search for "permuation in java" - first solution: [permutation](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/leetcode-permutations-java/). This code shows you the answer for one array. Take it and build it for three arrays.

Comment: Try to provide your code so far, and where you are stuck. Otherwise it´s unlikely that someone does solve your work for you.

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am new to SO...i have added my code as well now...guys please help if possible